# Include hash in translation JSON asset file name

Tags: angular, webpack, checksum, ngx-translate

I store my translation files as JSON in **/src/assets/i18n**. In order to bust cache, I want to fingerprint / include hash to the filename and use the hashed file named when I retrieve the file over HTTP. How do I accomplish this in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Going with the last method mentioned [here](https://netbasal.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-translation-files-in-angular-86143ee14c3c) as it's the most efficient. Thanks Netanel.